# mysql_fetch_array unable to get category id information

Tags: php, mysql, shopping-cart

When i click on Category list then i only get category 1 information. but mysql_fetch_array unable to get 2,3,4,5 id's information. code are here. help please:

**Category List:**

```
        $cat=mysql_query("select * from category");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($cat)){
        echo "<li><a href='index.php?cat_id=$row[id]'>$row[name]</a></li>";
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <br><br>

    <b>Cart</b>
    <div class="leftcon">
        <?php       
        mysql_select_db($dbname,$con);
        echo "<br>Coming Soon<br><br><br>";
        ?>
```

**Index page**

```
if($cat_id==null){
    $cat_id = 1;
}

$sql="select * from product where
    cat_id = $cat_id";
    echo $sql;
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$con);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){

    echo "<div class='con_product'>";
    echo "<b>$row[product_name]</b><br>";
    echo "<img src=$row[product_image] height='100' width='128'><br>";
    echo "$row[description]<br>";
    echo "<div class='con_product_price'><b>BDT $row[unit_price]</b></div>";
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_` function. It is very old/vulnerable.

Comment: You should probably be looking at $_GET['cat_id'] in your index page

Comment: do you actually see 2,3,4,5 etc.?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here

```
echo "<li><a href='index.php?cat_id=$row[id]'>$row[name]</a></li>";
```

The string is interpolated like this (equivalent to)

```
echo "<li><a href='index.php?cat_id=" . $row[id] . "'>" . $row[name] . "</a></li>";
```

But `id` is not a valid string or identifier.

So re-write your line like this:

```
echo "<li><a href='index.php?cat_id={$row['id']}'>{$row['name']}</a></li>";
```

or like this

```
echo "<li><a href='index.php?cat_id=" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</a></li>";
```

Also, you need to fix the other lines accordingly.

```
echo "<b>{$row['product_name']}</b><br>";
echo "<img src='{$row['product_image']}' height='100' width='128'><br>";
echo "{$row['description']}<br>";
echo "<div class='con_product_price'><b>BDT {$row['unit_price']}</b></div>";
```

---

**Another thing**

In your index.php,

```
if($cat_id==null){
    $cat_id = 1;
}
```

`$cat_id` is not defined anywhere. How do you define it? Maybe it should be

```
$cat_id = $_GET['cat_id'];
if($cat_id==null){
    $cat_id = 1;
}
```